# free() char with assigned value before call strdup()

Tags: c, free, strdup

I want to set mixer device from gtk_entry with this form "/dev/mixer:line" or "/dev/mixer:cd".

User must to entry in this format mixer device settings:

```
/dev/mixer:line

or:

/dev/mixer:cd
```

For this I write code to setup mixer and have same dilemma with strdup() function.
It is wrong to free() char with assigned value before call strdup()?

```
char *mixer_device = "/dev/mixer";
int mixer_channel = SOUND_MIXER_LINE;
int fd = -1;

int get_volume( void )
{
    int v, cmd, devs;
    int curvol = 0;

    if( fd < 0 ) fd = open( mixer_device, O_RDONLY );
    if( fd != -1 ) {

            ioctl( fd, SOUND_MIXER_READ_DEVMASK, &devs );
            if( devs & mixer_dev_mask ) {
                    cmd = MIXER_READ( mixer_channel );
            } else {
                    return curvol;
            }

            ioctl( fd, cmd, &v );
            curvol = ( v & 0xFF00 ) >> 8;
    }

    return curvol;
}

char *core_devnames[] = SOUND_DEVICE_NAMES;

int set_device( const char *devname )
{
    const char *channame;
    int i;

    /* if (mixer_device) free (mixer_device) <-- It is wrong ??? */ 
    mixer_device = strdup( devname );
    if( !mixer_device ) return -1;

    i = strcspn( mixer_device, ":" );
    if( i == strlen( mixer_device ) ) {
            channame = "line";
    } else {
            mixer_device[ i ] = 0;
            channame = mixer_device + i + 1;
    }
    fd = open( mixer_device, O_RDONLY );
    if( fd == 0 ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "mixer: Can't open device %s, "
                     "mixer volume and mute unavailable.\n", mixer_device );
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is wrong to free() char with assigned value before call strdup()

Comment: Calling `free` on non dynamically allocated memory is undefined behavior. You set the initial value to a string literal here: `char *mixer_device = "/dev/mixer";`

Answer (score 1):

You may only call `free()` if the pointer points to memory that was allocated with `malloc()`. In your program, `mixer_device` initially points to a literal string, so calling `free()` would cause undefined behavior.

Instead of checking whether `mixer_device` is null, you need another variable that keeps track of whether it points to the initial literal string or a new string created with `strdup()`. Or, instead of pointing it to a literal string, your startup code could do:

```
mixer_string = strdup("/dev/mixer");
```

so it's always safe to free it.

Answer (score 0):

You set the initial value here:

```
char *mixer_device = "/dev/mixer";
```

It now points to a string literal, so if you try to call `free` on `mixer_device` you will have [`undefined behavior`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), `free` can only be called on dynamically allocated memory, i.e. from `malloc`, `strdup` etc... One solution would be to use `strdup` to initialize your variable:

```
mixer_device = strdup("/dev/mixer") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize with NULL;

```
char *mixer_device = NULL;
```

It is OK to use `free(mixer_device)` when `mixer_device` has the value NULL or, of course, a value assigned through `malloc(), strdup(), realloc()`.  wHEN null, Nothing gets freed and no UB.  Then when ever you want to assign `mixer_device`, simply

```
free(mixer_device);
mixer_device = strdup(NewName);
```

At the end `main()`, perform a final

```
free(mixer_device);
```